# Azure Pipelines Nuget Restore Failing MSB4226

Tags: c#, azure, nuget, nuget-package-restore, azure-pipelines-yaml

I am trying to set up an Azure pipeline for a project but I am getting a failure on the nuget restore command in my yml.  Below is the full error:

> [error]The nuget command failed with exit code(1) and error(D:\a\1\s\UDesign\Backup\UDesign\UDesign.csproj(190,11): error MSB4226: The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" was not found. Also, tried to find "Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" in the fallback search path(s) for $(MSBuildExtensionsPath32) - "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild" . These search paths are defined in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\msbuild.exe.Config". Confirm that the path in the  declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk in one of the search paths.)
> ##[error]Packages failed to restore

Pretty much every post on this error is on the Build command in the YML but this is failing on the Nuget Restore:

[Pipelines failure image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4sWV7.png)

YML below:

```
# .NET Desktop
# Build and run tests for .NET Desktop or Windows classic desktop solutions.
# Add steps that publish symbols, save build artifacts, and more:
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/apps/windows/dot-net

trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'
    feedsToUse: 'select'
    vstsFeed: 'MyFeed'

- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:OutputPath="$(Build.BinariesDirectory)\$(Build.BuildID)"'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
    restoreNugetPackages: true
    msbuildArchitecture: 'x64'

- task: ArchiveFiles@2
  inputs:
    rootFolderOrFile: '$(Build.BinariesDirectory)\$(Build.BuildId)'
    includeRootFolder: false
    archiveType: 'zip'
    archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
    replaceExistingArchive: true

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    ArtifactName: 'drop'
    publishLocation: 'Container'
```

I am not sure if the issue is with the config somehow or my NuGet packages, I can't find much on this issue.

Comment: is UDesign.csproj part of the solution?

Comment: No it is not part of it

Comment: Do you have a [`nuget.config`](https://github.community/t/github-actions-automatically-push-nuget-package/128242/8) in the root of the solution?

Comment: No I am consuming an artifact feed, and based on the logs it looks like it is finding the packages correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try this

**Note:** You need to replace the source and target paths according to your project.

```
variables:
- name: BuildParameters.RestoreBuildProjects
  value: '**/*.csproj'
- name: BuildParameters.TestProjects
  value: '**/*[Tt]ests/*.csproj'
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - refs/heads/master
name: $(date:yyyyMMdd)$(rev:.r)
jobs:
- job: Job_1
  displayName: Agent job 1
  pool:
    vmImage: windows-2019
  steps:
  - checkout: self
  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: Restore
    inputs:
      command: restore
      projects: $(BuildParameters.RestoreBuildProjects)
  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: Build
    inputs:
      projects: $(BuildParameters.RestoreBuildProjects)
      arguments: --configuration $(BuildConfiguration)
  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: Test
    enabled: False
    inputs:
      command: test
      projects: $(BuildParameters.TestProjects)
      arguments: --configuration $(BuildConfiguration)
  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: Publish
    inputs:
      command: publish
      publishWebProjects: True
      projects: $(BuildParameters.RestoreBuildProjects)
      arguments: --configuration $(BuildConfiguration) --output $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)
      zipAfterPublish: True
  - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
    displayName: Publish Artifact
    condition: succeededOrFailed()
    inputs:
      PathtoPublish: $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)
      TargetPath: '\\my\share\$(Build.DefinitionName)\$(Build.BuildNumber)'
...
```

Comment: Someone who works on Azure DevOps, seems to be [suggesting to not use `task: DotnetCoreCLI`, and instead to just use a script task and run the dotnet CLI directly](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/15542#issuecomment-982091805).

Comment: Either way it fails as well, but with error: 

'
Build FAILED.

       "D:\a\1\s\Configurator\Configurator.csproj" (Restore target) (1) ->
         D:\a\1\s\Configurator\Configurator.csproj(1,1): error MSB4075: The project file "D:\a\1\s\Configurator\Configurator.csproj" must be opened in the Visual Studio IDE and converted to the latest version before it can be built by MSBuild.

    0 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:00.07
##[error]Error: The process 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe' failed with exit code 1
##[error]Packages failed to restore
'

Answer (score 0):

### Actual issue

The problem is actually unrelated to NuGet, it's just that NuGet is the first thing in your pipeline that tries to evaluate MSBuild files. If you look carefully at the error:

> error MSB4226: The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" was not found.

You can see that the error is that MSBuild can't find `Microsoft.WebApplication.targets`. What does this mean? I'm not 100% confident, but I do have high confidence that this means you're using a "self hosted" CI agent, not [a Microsoft hosted agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml), and whoever set up the machine installed Visual Studio 2019 without installing the ASP.NET workload. Therefore, whoever sets up your CI agents should install the "ASP.NET and web development" workload.

### Suggestion 1: CI agent should use BuildTools SKU

If you look at [VS's release and build history](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2019/history#release-dates-and-build-numbers), you see for every version, under "Links to Installer", there's a "BuildTools" link. This is a subset of Visual Studio without all the GUI stuff, meant for CI agents specifically. I don't think the BuildTools SKU has workload options, it just installs all the build tools necessary for all workloads.

Only in rare circumstances is the "full" Visual Studio required on a CI agent, so unless you know you're in that circumstance, I suggest installing the BuildTools on your CI agent instead of Enterprise or Professional.

### Suggestion 2: Don't use `NuGetCommand`

There's two reasons. Firstly, `NuGetCommand` is a task that uses NuGet.exe. The problem with NuGet.exe is that when you're using `PackageReference`, rather than `packages.config`, is that there are times when NuGet and the build tools (msbuild's props/targets) change file format for the temporary files. If you don't keep the version of NuGet.exe aligned with the version of MSBuild/Visual Studio, you might get build errors. So, it's much better to use `dotnet restore`, or if you can't use the dotnet cli, then use `msbuild -t:restore`. This way you're always using the exact version of NuGet that is designed for the version of dotnet/msbuild installed, and you'll never have to think about NuGet-MSBuild version problems again.

Secondly, [someone from the Azure DevOps team told my team that they want to deprecate these "heavy" tasks, and suggest customers call commands directly in a script task](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/15542#issuecomment-982018356). In particular, the way they implemented these features will break NuGet's new Package Source Mapping feature.

If your solution contains only SDK style projects, then I suggest you use:

```yaml
- task: NuGetAuthenticate
  displayName: Set up NuGet authentication
- script: dotnet restore $(solution)
  displayName: Restore
```

If your solution contains any "legacy" (non-SDK style) projects, then instead of using the dotnet CLI, use `- script: msbuild -t:restore $(solution)`.

### Suggestion 3: Don't use VSBuild

You're using the task `VSBuild` to run your build. This is a task that uses `devenv.com` to build the project. While devenv does have command line parameters to build from the command line, `msbuild.exe` is the "official" tool to do command line builds. Again, unless you know you're in a special circumstance that really needs to be built via `devenv /build`, I suggest you use the `dotnet` CLI or `MSBuild` instead. As previously mentioned, the Azure DevOps team apparently want to deprecate the "heavy" tasks, so I suggest you use a script and call `dotnet` or `msbuild` directly.

```yaml
- script: msbuild -t:build $(solution)
  displayName: Build solution
```

Comment: This this valid Yml in Azure? This doesn't seem to conform to the tasks that are available to be set up for my pipeline.  For example none of the tasks you linked seem to be valid yml according to the builder?  Fwiw switching to DotNetCoreCLI and running restore seems to have helped but that doesn't make a lot of sense to me since we are not using core.  Further, it fails on MSBuild and can't find any nuget packages from the restore so I am not sure that is the correct solution here.

Comment: Restore:
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    projects: '**/*.sln'
    feedsToUse: 'select'
    vstsFeed: 'Feed'
    noCache: true
MSBuild:
- task: MSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '**/MyProject.sln'

Comment: Also as a follow up, we are using a windows hosted agent at specified in the posted yaml: windows-latest, not self hosted

Comment: it's a snippet rather than a complete yaml file, but yes, it's valid. [Here's the docs for the `script` keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema%2Cparameter-schema#script), assuming that's what you think is invalid. Otherwise I'm not sure what you think is invalid.

Comment: If any project uses packages.config, then [as per nuget's docs, you need to use `msbuild -t:restore -p:RestorePackagesConfig=true`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/msbuild-targets#restoring-packagereference-and-packagesconfig-projects-with-msbuild). Otherwise, I don't have enough information to help understand why build fails with missing packages. This is one of the reasons I personally don't like Azure DevOps' NuGetCommand and MSBuild tasks, because it's more difficult to do simple things like pass arguments that you want. I prefer to just run the command line myself.

Comment: Finally, sorry that I missed that you're already using the hosted agents. I really don't have any ideas without being able to see your project file myself and possibly doing a little debugging.

Comment: After creating a new ASP.NET web app, I see [these same two imports in my csproj](https://github.com/NuGet/NuGetGallery/blob/a929ae1b53a5bfdead4475e33819032b8e3f97a6/src/NuGetGallery/NuGetGallery.csproj#L2334-L2335). Notice `Condition="false"` on the import that is failing in your build, making me believe your project does not have the false condition, and therefore the project only works in old versions of Visual Studio, not VS2019 (on windows-latest), or VS2022. Like one of the error messages you copy/pasted here, I think you need to update your projects to suppert newer versions of VS.